# Find $\oint xdx+2ydy+3zdz$ on the line segment formed by points $A(1,0,-1)$,$B(2,5,-1)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, calculus

Find $\oint xdx+2ydy+3zdz$ on the line segment formed by points $A(1,0,-1)$,$B(2,5,-1)$

**My approach:**
First I find the line segment formed by $A,B$ which is $\vec l(t)=\vec{OA}+t\vec{AB}=(1,0,-1)+t(1,5,0),0\leq t\leq 1$

Then I get $$x=1+t,dx=dt$$ $$y=5t,dy=5dt$$ $$z=-1,dz=0$$

The integral now becomes $\oint 1+51t dt$ and if I calculate in the range of $t$ I find the result $\frac{53}{2}$

**Second thoughts:**
I am not completely convinced that the result above is correct since the integral is given in the form $\oint\vec Fds$ and we know that the work done by a force in a closed curve is zero.

At this point I would like a clarification in order to eliminate any confusion and decide for the correct result, thanks.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Why is this a physics question?

Comment: Because of the work of the force and conservative fields!

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1452455/11127

Comment: It is no longer crossposted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line segment is not a closed curve, so your integral is not an integral over a closed curve, it is just a line integral; so your answer is correct. However, if you must insist that your integral is an integral over a closed curve, then you can consider the (degenerate) closed curve formed by going from A to B and then from B to A, in which case your result would be zero.

About the work done by a force over a closed cyrve, well, it is not always zero. It is zero if the force is conservative, which means that it can be derived by the gradient of a scalar potential or, equivallently, that the curl of the force is the zero vector.

Comment: Well I agree that a line is not a closed curve. I wrote closed curve because of the symbol of the integral.Does $\oint$ mean integral in closed curve? This is the reason of my confusion!

Comment: Yes, the circle around the integral means closed.

Comment: It does. However, this integral is **not** over a closed curve so the little circe in the integral must be a typo (assuming that the author does know mathematics).

Comment: if the integral was indeed zero, shouldn't I take zero as a result from the integral calculation in boundaries of t?

Comment: if the integral were indeed closed then you should get zero as a result; this is what happens if you force it to be closed by considering the degenerate closed curved described before

Comment: @user3257624 I see though that if $\vec F=(x,2y,3z)$ then $curl\vec F=0$.. so the integral should be zero?

Comment: if it is closed indeed, yes: it is a direct consequence of Stoke's theorem. If not then you cannot apply this theorem. Make clear whether the closed integral symbol is a typo or not and then decide whether it isn't zero on if it is, respectively

Answer (score 2):

The answer that you calculate is correct, but I think some clarification is in order. First, notice that you are asked to integrate a line segment, not a closed curve, so you should have no reason to expect that the answer should be zero. Second, $\oint \vec{F} \cdot ds=0$ only for conservative vector fields $\vec{F}$. Being a conservative vector field means that 
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0,
\end{equation}
or equivalently
\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = \nabla \phi,
\end{equation}
for some scalar field $\phi$. One useful trick for conservative vector fields that you can use even when you are not integrating over a closed curve is that you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to write
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b \vec{F}\cdot ds = \int_a^b (\nabla\phi)\cdot ds = \phi(b) - \phi(a).
\end{equation}

As a bonus: The equivalence of the two statements
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = \nabla \phi
\end{equation} actually does not hold in general but depends on the topology of the space you are working in. For example, if the space you are working in is the plane with the origin removed, then statements such as this will fail in general and there will exist vector fields $\vec{F}$ whose curl is zero, but which cannot be written as the gradient of some globally defined function $\phi$. The mathematical tool known as De Rham Cohomology allows us (in a loose sense) to measure how many such vector fields exist in a given space.